# Changing order of where clauses breaks the query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I ran into this case using MySQL 5.6:

This query works and returns expected results:

```sql
select *
from some_table
where a = 'b'
and metadata->>"$.country" is not null;
```

However, this query (the only difference is the order of where clauses) returns an error

```sql
select *
from some_table
where metadata->>"$.country" is not null
and a = 'b';
```

The error MySQL returns is

> Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Invalid value." at position 0.

Why?

Comment: Try to wrap in parenthesis: `where (metadata->>"$.country" is not null)`

Comment: Tried just now. Same error

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a sqlfiddle?

Comment: I'll try but seems to be down right now. Or is that just me?

Comment: Try https://www.db-fiddle.com/ it's more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `metdata` column contains malformed JSON for at least one row in the table.

We'd expect that entirely removing the `a = 'b'` condition, we would also observe the same error.

I suspect that the difference in behavior is due to the order of operations being performed. When the `a = 'b'` condition is evaluated first, that excludes rows before the `JSON_EXTRACT(metadata)` expression is evaluated. Since the row doesn't match the `a = 'b'` condition, MySQL takes a shortcut, it doesn't evaluate the `JSON_EXTRACT`, it already knows the row is going to be excluded.

When the comparisons are done in a different order, with the `JSON_EXTRACT` function executed first, the error is raised when the expression is evaluated for a rows with invalid JSON in `metadata`.

---

Summary:

There's at least one row in the table that has malformed JSON stored in `metadata` column.

The difference in the observed behavior of the two queries is due to a different order of operations.

Suggestion:

Consider using the `JSON_VALID` function to identify rows with invalid values.

---

Excerpt from MySQL Reference Manual

`JSON_EXTRACT`

> Returns data from a JSON document, selected from the parts of the document matched by the path arguments. Returns NULL if any argument is NULL or no paths locate a value in the document. ***An error occurs if the json_doc argument is not a valid JSON document*** or any path argument is not a valid path expression.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract

`JSON_VALID`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-valid

Comment: Interesting. You're right that removing the other where clause causes the same error. I'll check what rows are invalid with your recommendation.

Comment: You are exactly right. There are 6 rows in the database with malformed JSON. All of these have value `a` set to something other than `"b"`, as you guessed when scoping to `a = "b"` first, it ignores those and the query runs without any problems.